# php copiar un archivo con ñ

Tags: php

intento copiar `./origen/viñas.png` en `./select/vinas.png`. El fichero `./origen/viñas.png` existe, de hecho puedo copiar otros archivos pero no los que tienen **ñ**.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
$f="viñas.png";
$f1="vinas.png";

copy("./origen/".$f,"./select/".$fl);
```

El mensaje de errror:

> Warning: copy(./origen/viñas.png): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in

Comment: En que sistema operativo corre el PHP?

Comment: la solución es usar iconv, en tu código en la linea de copy hay un error L $fl debe ser $f1

Answer (score 2):

Es probable que tenga que ver con la codificación de caracteres.
Prueba:

```
copy("./origen/".utf8_decode($f),"./select/".$fl);
```

ó:

```
copy("./origen/".utf8_encode($f),"./select/".$fl); //editado
```

Normalmente, si haces

```
print_r(scandir('./origen/'));
```

verás caracteres extraños por la diferencia de codificación cuando utilices eñes, tildes, cedillas, etc.

También puede ser un problema de permisos del fichero.

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario saber que `charset` usa cada sistema de archivos.
el literal "viñas.png" está definido como `UTF8` y el sistema de archivos de windows los nombres los guarda usando `ISO-8859-1`.

Debes convertir usando la función `iconv` de PHP

```
$f=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1","viñas.png");
$f1="vinas.png";

copy("./origen/".$f,"./select/".$f1);
```

Probado con Windows10 con xampp, funciona correctamente

Comment: Ahora estoy en windows 7 pero la idea es que se ejecute con cualquier sistema opertivo